# Cannot run program "wsimport": CreateProcess in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsimport

This question is for java web service beginners.
  If you are facing issue to **make build** or for generating **Client** code in **web service**. 
 So I would like to suggest you follow bellow steps:-

> 1) Open your eclipse, i'm sure it shall be open only :) 
>  2) Now go
>   to **File > Properties** or just say (  <kbd>ALT</kbd> +   <kbd>Enter</kbd>    )** 
>  3) You shall
>   be prompted with new window Named **"Properties"** 
>  4)Here look
>   for the **Java Build Path** , then check for the Installed JRE of your
>   eclipse. 
>  5)If path is given only JRE but not jdk, Please change
>   it **immediately**

This the only thing which was not allowing you to call **wsimport** command.
Because **wsimport** is an **exe** file which resides in **JDK/bin directory** not in  **JRE directory** 
That is why you always get such issue not able to execute command.
Now enjoy your learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [Apache Ant](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-80_ant.htm?cp=0_1_2) for generate the client of WebService on eclipse using the [`wsimport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool from JDK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="generate-client" default="generate-client" basedir=".">

    <property name="java.home" value="C:\Software\Java\jdk1.7.0_05" />
    <property name="wsdl.location" 
           value="http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL" />

    <target name="generate-client">
        <exec executable="${java.home}\bin\wsimport.exe">
            <arg line="${wsdl.location} -s src -Xdebug -verbose -Xnocompile" />
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

Put this XML file in your project folder.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but sorry i was just kept my answer with my question here. I wanted to describe solution for such issues.

Comment: Is there a particular name that I should use for this .xml file?  Naming convention?